# How to get this OUTPUT? perl/awk/sed? How?

Tags: text-processing

How can I generate from this INPUT in "general"

INPUT (/proc/net/ip_conntrack)

```
udp      17 0 src=192.168.1.128 dst=91.120.112.125 sport=29249 dport=39802 packets=3 bytes=408 [UNREPLIED] src=91.120.112.125 dst=79.132.235.112 sport=39802 dport=29249 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 use=2
udp      17 146 src=192.168.1.128 dst=98.196.37.3 sport=56932 dport=43645 packets=924 bytes=406167 src=98.196.37.3 dst=79.132.235.112 sport=43645 dport=56932 packets=1042 bytes=546092 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
tcp      6 118 SYN_SENT src=192.168.1.129 dst=89.132.51.110 sport=2518 dport=47385 packets=2 bytes=104 [UNREPLIED] src=80.132.51.190 dst=79.132.235.112 sport=47385 dport=2518 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 use=2
udp      17 147 src=192.168.1.128 dst=98.196.37.7 sport=56937 dport=43647 packets=924 bytes=406167 src=98.196.37.7 dst=80.132.235.117 sport=43647 dport=56937 packets=1042 bytes=546092 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
tcp      6 119 SYN_SENT src=192.168.1.129 dst=89.132.51.110 sport=2514 dport=47384 packets=2 bytes=104 [UNREPLIED] src=80.132.51.194 dst=80.132.235.114 sport=47384 dport=2514 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 use=2
udp      17 163 src=192.168.1.111 dst=192.168.1.201 sport=67 dport=68 packets=29 bytes=9512 src=192.168.1.201 dst=192.168.1.1 sport=68 dport=67 packets=27 bytes=8856 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
tcp      6 1 TIME_WAIT src=192.168.1.201 dst=67.201.31.15 sport=55479 dport=80 packets=7 bytes=725 src=67.201.31.35 dst=79.132.235.112 sport=80 dport=55479 packets=5 bytes=1963 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
```

to this output?

OUTPUT

```
udp 192.168.1.128   3
tcp 192.168.1.129   2
udp 192.168.1.111   1
tcp 192.168.1.201   1
```

So that from the INPUT datas the OUTPUT would be 3 columns:

```
protocoll   src-ip-address  count-connection-numbers
```

So that the IP with the most number of connections would be at top.

Answer (score 6):

Using **sed**, **uniq**, **sort**, **awk** and **column**:

```
sed -n -r 's/^(udp|tcp)\s*[^=]*=([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*$/\1 \2/p' infile \
  | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$1'} | column -t > outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps: extract the protocol and source addresses, and collect and sort. You [already know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15353/find-connections-per-ip-on-an-openwrt-router) how to do the second, so let's see how to do the first.

You [already had](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15353/find-connections-per-ip-on-an-openwrt-router/15396#15396) a way to extract the source addresses:

```
sed -ne 's/^.*src=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

That extracts the last `src=` field though; here we want to extract the first. It's a bit inconvenient in sed, but can be done.

```
sed -n -e 's/\(src=[^ ]*\).*/\1/' -e 's/^.*src=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

To retain the first field, just apply the last replacement to the part after the first space.

```
sed -n -e 's/\(src=[^ ]*\).*/\1/' -e 's/ .*src=\([^ ]*\).*/ \1/p'
```

This is terse and not very clear. Here's an about equally terse, but clearer way to get the same output with awk. Call `match` to find the extent of the first `src=` field, then print out the corresponding part of the line.

```
awk 'match($0, / src=[^ ]*/) {print $1 substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

Finally, pipe into the second stage (sort, obtain counts, and sort by count).

```
awk 'match($0, / src=[^ ]*/) {print $1 substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' |
sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: `s/ .*src=` makes a greedy grab and returns the 2nd src= ip..  One alternative is `'s/ [^=]*=`

Comment: @fred I shouldn't post so late at night, I hadn't even noticed the second `src=` field. `s/ [^=]*=\([^ ]*\)/\1/p` would work, but it would rely on `src=` being the first field with an equal sign, and that feels too inflexible. *(P.S. I forget, do you do Perl? You may be interested in this [text replacement benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430964/perl-regex-substitute-from-hash/6435950#6435950).)*

Comment: I too hadn't noticed the second `src=` until after I had  +1'd your answer, based on a visual 'test', and then thought I'd better give it a 'real' test... Re. `perl`: I look on in awe :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl one-liner to get it done, it's very easy!

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $1" if /src=(.*?)\s/' /proc/net/ip_conntrack | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn -k 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and `sort`:

```
/usr/bin/awk -F" " '
{
  proto = $1
  for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) 
  {
    if ($i ~ /^src=/) 
    { 
      scrip = $i
      srcip = sub(/^src=/, "", scrip)
      key = proto SUBSEP scrip
      a[key]+=1
    }
  }
}
END {
  for (var in a)
  {
    split(var, subkey, SUBSEP)
    printf "%-5s %-18s %-8s\n", subkey[1], subkey[2], a[var]
  }
}
' infile | sort -rn -k3,3
```

Comment: Your output prints both instances (per line) of `src=`... The sample output requires only the first instance...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;

# extract protocol and source-ip-address, count rows with same values
while(<>) {
  if (/^([^ ]+).*src=([0-9.]+)/) {
    $count{"$1 $2"}++;
  }
}

# sort by count
for my $p_src (sort {$count{$b} <=> $count{$a}} keys %count) {
  print "$p_src\t$count{$p_src}\n";
}
```

Example (your data isn't very interesting)

```
$ eg.pl eg.txt
tcp 67.201.31.35        1
tcp 80.132.51.190       1
tcp 80.132.51.194       1
udp 192.168.1.201       1
udp 91.120.112.125      1
udp 98.196.37.3 1
udp 98.196.37.7 1
```

Comment: Based on the sample output provided, only the first instance (per line) of `src=` ip should be printed...